# Using Enum to hold object constants

Tags: java, enums, constants

So I've learned a bunch recently so I'm going back and sort of refactoring the homeworks from a previous course that I took to implement them using good practices. One homework had us implement a Planner object that contained an array of Course objects. I'm trying to create some Course constants so that I can access some popular Courses without having to create brand new Objects every time and so I can easily access them without going through the Course building process. I don't have much experience with enums and I can't seem to find anything on how I can actually use an Enum to store constants that are Objects. I originally wanted to make them constants in the Course class but Effective Java insists enumns should be used in such a situation. Does my implementation make sense at all? How should I go about making this enum that contains Course constants so I can actually retrieve them? I use the Builder method for creating a Course.

```
public enum Courses {
    CSE_114, CSE_214, CSE_219, CSE_215;

    private final static Course CSE_114_COURSE = new Course
        .Builder("Computer Science 1", "Paul Fodor", 114)
        .section((byte)1).department("CSE").build();

    private static final Course CSE_214_COURSE = new Course
        .Builder("Data Structures", "Ahmad Esmaili", 214)
        .section((byte)1).department("CSE").build();

    private static final Course CSE_219_COURSE = new Course
        .Builder("Software Development", "Richard McKenna", 219)
        .section((byte)1).department("CSE").build();

    private static final Course CSE_215_COURSE = new Course
        .Builder("Foundations of CS", "Paul Fodor", 215)
        .section((byte)1).department("CSE").build();

    public static Course get(Courses c) {
        switch(c) {
            case CSE_114: return CSE_114_COURSE;
            case CSE_214: return CSE_214_COURSE;
            case CSE_219: return CSE_219_COURSE;
            case CSE_215: return CSE_215_COURSE;
            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Course does not exist.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why didn't you use a Map<String, Course> instead of going for enums?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I was just interested in how I could use enums to hold a bunch of constants but in the end I realized an enum wasn't necessary at all. I've never actually used maps very much. I understand the concept and that actually sounds like a good idea since I could just retrieve courses by name and have it be O(1). If I was to use a map, where do you think would be the right place for it? In a CourseManager class like before?

Comment: You could just use a Map instead of the CourseManager class. If you wanted additional functionality, like loading from file or network, *then* you would definitely want to create a specific CourseManager class, which would probably contain a Map and some other utility methods.

Answer (score 6):

You can actually treat an enum like an object:

```
public enum Course {
    CSE_114("Computer Science 1", "Paul Fodor");

    public final String room;
    public final String lecturer;

    private Course(room, lecturer) {
        this.room = room;
        this.lecturer = lecturer;
    }
}
```

Because it is an enum, all values must be known at compile time. This is enforced by the Java language, which requires that the enum constructor is private.

While this would work for your situation, I don't recommend it - in fact, **I don't recommend using an enum at all**. An enum represents a fixed, known set of values. If you want to create more courses at runtime, then the enum is incomplete, and that contradicts the definition of an enum.

Instead, I suggest you use a CourseManager. Create one class, which holds the collection of all known courses. Then, when you need a course, you request it by name.

```
Course cs114 = courses.get("CS 114");
```

You could also take it one step further, by instantiating the CourseManager from a file, which contains a list of courses in a basic format like JSON.

Comment: Yes new Courses would be created at runtime since the point was to allow a user to create and add custom courses to a planner. I certainly won't enumerate every single Course so now I understand that enum should only be used when you know all the values. But why would creating a class to hold the Course constants be better than just putting the constants in the Course class? Couldn't I just make a static get method like the one you showed in the Course class to get specific Course instances?

Comment: Creating a class to hold the courses has two main advantages - it can be instantiated from file, database, or some other source, and you can add or rename courses and the 'get' method will still work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a bad implementation but I think a have a bit better solution: add an abstract method to your enum definition.

```
public enum Courses {
    CSE_114 {
        public Course getCourse() {
            return CSE_114_COURSE;
        }
    }
    ...

    private final static Course CSE_114_COURSE = new Course
        .Builder("Computer Science 1", "Paul Fodor", 114)
        .section((byte)1).department("CSE").build();

    ...

    public abstract Course getCourse();

}
```

That way you can access to any course object vía `Courses.CSE_114.getCourse()` and you are also forcing that every `enum` has a course (imagine that you add an enum constant but forgot to add it in the get method. The way I proposed makes that scenario non sense)

Comment: Constant-specific methods here are better than the proposed method with the switch-case block.  But really, the data wrapped into the `Course` objects should just be directly associated with the enum constants themselves to yield an even better solution.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The solution I proposed would be the first step that, ideally, would evolution into a better solution (yours)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing enum constants with static constants. Get these courses and selection of courses out of the enum class. Or you can use something like Andrew Williamson showed. Just don't  mix the static constants with the enums. Static constants don't belong to the enum class. Enum class has a fixed set of values and that is where its role ends.  All the other  logic using these enums should be done somewhere else

Comment: *"Enum class has a fixed set of values and that is where its role ends...."* ... I can't agree.  An enum is an ordinary java class in every way that matters except that it has more refined semantics.  A Java rich enum type *should* associate behavior and values with the enum constants in any case in which it makes sense to do so.  That is part of what makes Java enum types so much more powerful than enums in some other languages.  The solution proposed by Williamson above that associates values with the constants is more on the right track.

Comment: I agree with the approach of Andrew Williamson., But my emphasis is on using the enum class appropriately, the questioner is simply misusing the enum class to make it as a java class while the instension of enum is to make things more typesafe.. adding  static constants inside an enum is never a good idea even if java allows so

Comment: You're right I was getting them mixed up and didn't know that an enum should contain all possible values not just some. It's just everytime constants are mentioned I see enums being brought up and how  they should be used to contain constants.